Why installing Arch linux on virtual box in Windows 11 OS shows boot error?
Installing Arch linux causes issues when trying to configure boot like this:
[root@archiso /]# mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivarfs/
mount: /sys/firmware/efi/efivarfs/: fsopen system call failed: Operation not supported. dmesg (1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
[root@archiso /]# 

Even this type of method of grub is used where it SHOULD BE LIKE THIS as shown below:
[root@archiso /]# grub-install /dev/sda Installing for x86_64-efi platform. Installation finished. No error reported. 
[root@archiso/]# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partiti Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ..
done
[root@archiso /]#

However, I do NOT get this to work as well in my virtual box as it shows error (I forgot to copy that error message). So can you guys help me fix this issue.
My Virtual box info
Arch ISO: archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso
General
Name: ArchISO
Operating System: Arch Linux (64-bit)
System
Base Memory: 9216 MB
Processors: 4
Boot Order: Floppy, Optical, Hard Disk
Acceleration: Nested Paging, KVM Paravirtualization
Display
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
Video Memory: 128 MB
Acceleration: 3D
Remote Desktop Server: Disabled
Recording: Disabled
Storage
Controller: IDE Secondary Device 0: [Optical Drive] archlinux-2024.07.01-x86_64.iso (1.09 GB)
Controller: SATA
SATA Port 0:           ArchISO.vdi (Normal, 80.00 GB)
